# Intel PARDISO factorization slower when linking dynamically

Tags: c++, linux, intel-mkl

We have a code that runs PARDISO solver. When we link this code statically, the factorization step is 2x faster than when we link the same code dinamically.

Here are link lines obtained from CMake in both cases (I've used the MKL link line advisor to help me define the parameters):

**Static linking:**

```
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/bin/intel64/icpc    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/simplesolver.dir/pardiso_sym_c.cpp.o  -o simplesolver -Wl,--start-group /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

**Dynamic linking:**

```
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/bin/intel64/icpc   
-rdynamic CMakeFiles/simplesolver.dir/pardiso_sym_c.cpp.o  -o simplesolver
-L/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Is there any known issue with this? or we are missing some compilation/linking flags to improve factorization performance? The code is exactly the same (solverc example from the MKL distribution). The only thing we change is how to link, and then we obtain this big difference in running speed.

We are using Intel Compiler C++ 2016 and using the MKL from it, under Linux (Ubuntu 14.04). We measure the time by looking at the output of PARDISO (msglvl=1).

Only if it helps, this is the code (I've ommited the function readData that reads the matrix information from a file).

```
#include "mkl_pardiso.h"
#include "mkl_types.h"

#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


MKL_INT main (void)
{
        int n; // dimension of matrix
    int nnz; // number of non zeroes
    int* ia; // coordinates in i of each value in a
    int* ja; // coordinates in j of each value in a
    double* a; // values of the matrix
    double* b; // vector of forces
    double* x_expected; // computed solution our software (Ax=rhs)
    double* x; // computed solution in pardiso

    bool result = false;

    std::string fileIn = "problemData.bin";

    //METHOD THAT FILLS ALL THE VALUES... NOT RELEVANT.
    result = readData(fileIn, n, nnz, &ia, &ja, &a, &b, &x_expected, false);
    x = new double[n];
    if (!result)
        return 1;



    MKL_INT mtype = -2;       /* Real symmetric matrix */
    /* RHS and solution vectors. */

    MKL_INT nrhs = 1;     /* Number of right hand sides. */
    /* Internal solver memory pointer pt, */
    /* 32-bit: int pt[64]; 64-bit: long int pt[64] */
    /* or void *pt[64] should be OK on both architectures */
    void *pt[64];
    /* Pardiso control parameters. */
    MKL_INT iparm[64];
    MKL_INT maxfct, mnum, phase, error, msglvl;
    /* Auxiliary variables. */
    MKL_INT i;
    double ddum;          /* Double dummy */
    MKL_INT idum;         /* Integer dummy. */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* .. Setup Pardiso control parameters. */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    for ( i = 0; i < 64; i++ )
    {
        iparm[i] = 0;
    }
    iparm[0] = 1;         /* No solver default */
    iparm[1] = 2;         /* Fill-in reordering from METIS */
    iparm[3] = 0;         /* No iterative-direct algorithm */
    iparm[4] = 0;         /* No user fill-in reducing permutation */
    iparm[5] = 0;         /* Write solution into x */
    iparm[6] = 0;         /* Not in use */
    iparm[7] = 2;         /* Max numbers of iterative refinement steps */
    iparm[8] = 0;         /* Not in use */
    iparm[9] = 13;        /* Perturb the pivot elements with 1E-13 */
    iparm[10] = 1;        /* Use nonsymmetric permutation and scaling MPS */
    iparm[11] = 0;        /* Not in use */
    iparm[12] = 0;        /* Maximum weighted matching algorithm is switched-off (default for symmetric). Try iparm[12] = 1 in case of inappropriate accuracy */
    iparm[13] = 0;        /* Output: Number of perturbed pivots */
    iparm[14] = 0;        /* Not in use */
    iparm[15] = 0;        /* Not in use */
    iparm[16] = 0;        /* Not in use */
    iparm[17] = -1;       /* Output: Number of nonzeros in the factor LU */
    iparm[18] = -1;       /* Output: Mflops for LU factorization */
    iparm[19] = 0;        /* Output: Numbers of CG Iterations */
    maxfct = 1;           /* Maximum number of numerical factorizations. */
    mnum = 1;         /* Which factorization to use. */
    msglvl = 1;           /* Print statistical information in file */
    error = 0;            /* Initialize error flag */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* .. Initialize the internal solver memory pointer. This is only */
/* necessary for the FIRST call of the PARDISO solver. */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    for ( i = 0; i < 64; i++ )
    {
        pt[i] = 0;
    }
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* .. Reordering and Symbolic Factorization. This step also allocates */
/* all memory that is necessary for the factorization. */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    phase = 11;
    PARDISO (pt, &maxfct, &mnum, &mtype, &phase,
             &n, a, ia, ja, &idum, &nrhs, iparm, &msglvl, &ddum, &ddum, &error);
    if ( error != 0 )
    {
        printf ("\nERROR during symbolic factorization: %d", error);
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("\nReordering completed ... ");
    printf ("\nNumber of nonzeros in factors = %d", iparm[17]);
    printf ("\nNumber of factorization MFLOPS = %d", iparm[18]);
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* .. Numerical factorization. */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    phase = 22;
    PARDISO (pt, &maxfct, &mnum, &mtype, &phase,
             &n, a, ia, ja, &idum, &nrhs, iparm, &msglvl, &ddum, &ddum, &error);
    if ( error != 0 )
    {
        printf ("\nERROR during numerical factorization: %d", error);
        return -2;
    }
    printf ("\nFactorization completed ... ");
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* .. Back substitution and iterative refinement. */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    phase = 33;
    iparm[7] = 2;         /* Max numbers of iterative refinement steps. */

    PARDISO (pt, &maxfct, &mnum, &mtype, &phase,
             &n, a, ia, ja, &idum, &nrhs, iparm, &msglvl, b, x, &error);
    if ( error != 0 )
    {
        printf ("\nERROR during solution: %d", error);
        return -3;
    }
    printf ("\nSolve completed ... ");
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* .. Termination and release of memory. */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    phase = -1;           /* Release internal memory. */
    PARDISO (pt, &maxfct, &mnum, &mtype, &phase,
             &n, &ddum, ia, ja, &idum, &nrhs,
             iparm, &msglvl, &ddum, &ddum, &error);


    delete [] ia;
    delete [] ja;
    delete [] a;
    delete [] b;
    delete [] x;
    delete [] x_expected;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have turned on 0 optimisations. A lot of factors would then contribute to runtime behaviour that are not at all related to MKL / dynamic vs static linking etc. What happens, when you compile above code with `-O2 -g -march=native`, `-O3 -march=native`? The differences should go away entirely.

Comment: I am using optimization O3 in compilation. What I posted was only the linking command. The optimization flags are the same in both configurations. I guess I should not use march=native because the compilation and execution machines are no the same and the processors are different (Xeon VS i7).

Comment: correct, do not use `-march=native` if hardware is not identical. but you could build for target box with `-march=corei7-avx`. nevertheless i am speechless about the differences.